# Removing border on ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to remove the border which is between the border of ListView and ListViewItem which looks like it is a border of LVItem.
I really need to get rid of it, since I wanna the selected item to be connected with the right lightgray area. (Sure without that white border which was only testing border, to see whats going on with those borders in listview)

[image]

This is my styling code:
http://pastebin.com/TH83CaL0

And my listview xaml code looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/zvyJem02

Edit:
I am newbie with wpf and xaml, since I started with 1 week ago.

Comment: why did you paste you entire template here 
paste only the part which is relevant to your question and what you tried to do , nobody's gonna sit and go through all that XAML
-1

Comment: Because i started with wpf and xaml 1 week ago?

Comment: @eranotzap is correct, create a *small* yet *complete* example of your problem, instead of making us work through all that code...

Comment: I think you can't get rid of this border only by Styling, but you could move the "right lightgray area" a little to the left and let it overlap your ListView by setting `Margin="-1.5 0 0 0" Panel.ZIndex="1"`.

Comment: Tnx a lot Florian GI, I forgot the margin solution, is not the same you've wrote (I just add a margin -1 of ListView, and now those borders are somewhere behind), but helped me out to fix my problem. Tnx a lot again!

Comment: @FlorianGl You should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't get rid of this border only by Styling, but you could move the "right lightgray area" a little to the left and let it overlap your ListView by setting `Margin="-1.5 0 0 0" Panel.ZIndex="1"` or (as you did) hide a little of the ListBox behind the gray area by setting its `Margin="-1"`.